# how to create cron that post events daily in wordpress?

Tags: posts

I want a cron that post events daily. I want to set cron programmatically

```
function cp_remove_sold_ads(){

    global $wpdb;
    // Get all sold ads
    $sold_ads = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "postmeta WHERE `meta_key` = 'cp_ad_sold_date' AND `meta_value` <> ''");

    foreach ($sold_ads as $ad) {
        $today = time();

        // Get day, month, year
        $date = explode('-',get_post_meta($ad->post_id, 'cp_ad_sold_date', true));

        $sold_date = mktime(null, null, null, $date[1], $date[2], $date[0]);
        $date_diff = $today - $sold_date;

        // Get the days difference
        $sold_day_diff = floor($date_diff / (60*60*24));

        if ($sold_day_diff >= 5) {
            wp_update_post(array('ID' => $ad->post_id, 'post_status' => 'draft'));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has a cron API and if you want to use it you can do it with `wp_schedule_event` function. This function should be called only on ativiation of the plugin and the scheduled event should be cleared on deactivation of the plugin. For example:

```
 register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'cyb_activation' );
 function cyb_activation() {
     wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'cyb_daily_event_hook' );
 }

 add_action( 'cyb_daily_event_hook', 'cyb_do_this_daily' );
 function cyb_do_this_daily() {
      // do something every day
 }

 register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'cyb_deactivation' );
 function cyb_deactivation() {
     wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'cyb_daily_event_hook' );
 }
```

The function `cyb_do_this_daily()` will perform what you want to do every day. That is, the function you posted. In that function you are building a query to `post_meta` table, I think you should use a `WP_Query` object or `get_posts()` instead of a direct query. For example (not tested, just passed your query to WP_Query):

```
function cyb_do_this_daily(){

     // Get all sold ads
     $args = array(
         'meta_key'     = 'cp_ad_sold_date',
         'meta_value'   = '',
         'meta_compare' = '!='
     );

     $sold_ads = new WP_Query( $args );

     while( $sold_ads->have_posts() ) {

         $sold_ads->next_post()
         $ad = $sold_ads->post;
         $today = time();

         // Get day, month, year
         $date = explode('-',get_post_meta($ad->ID, 'cp_ad_sold_date', true));

         $sold_date = mktime(null, null, null, $date[1], $date[2], $date[0]);
         $date_diff = $today - $sold_date;

        // Get the days difference
        $sold_day_diff = floor($date_diff / (60*60*24));

        if ($sold_day_diff >= 5) {
             wp_update_post(array('ID' => $ad->ID, 'post_status' => 'draft'));
        }

    }

    wp_reset_postdata();

 }
```